Looking for a short story with robot judges
I'm researching current developments in AI & Law, including aspects that have been fictionalised. I came across a Reddit thread a few months ago, I think, where someone mentioned a short story (or comic?) where a society had replaced their judges with machines/robots. Unless this memory is completely fabricated, I think it was on another planet. My Google searches have been full of Asimov short stories, but I don't think it was one of his. Anyone have an idea?
EDIT: thank you so much for these first answers! For added context:

There's a non-zero chance that this is a fabricated memory
I wrote short story because that’s what I seem to remember, but could also have been a novel or comic, or a story part of other short stories.
I would be able to recognise it if found, especially because I thought I had added it to my Zotero library (there are so many items there that scrolling though them would be pointless)
The description I seem to remember was more about another world/planet/society where all judges were robots/machines/AIs (think isekai).


Would you be able to ID the correct story if someone posted it? I think there is more than one candidate.

@OrganicMarble That was my thought too. The way to prove it would be by citing some other examples, but I couldn't think of any offhand. Are we looking for stories about robot judges, or stories with robot judges as part of the background? What candidates did you have in mind?

@user14111 https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ComputerizedJudicialSystem

@OrganicMarble Of the examples from Literature on that TV Tropes page,: Dickson's "Computers Don't Argue" could possibly be an answer..

There's also Gladiator at Law, although there are still some human judges in that book, for trying important cases.

@Buzz The question asked for a short story and Gladiator at Law is a novel, so I think we can rule it out.

"The Cyber and Justice Holmes" by Frank Riley, available at Project Gutenberg, is a short story about one of the last human judges in a world with robot judges. However, it is set on a future Earth, not another planet.
Editorial blurb:

Old Judge Anderson feared the inevitable—he
was to be replaced by a Cyber! A machine that
dealt out decisions free of human errors and
emotions. What would Justice Holmes think?

Excerpts:

"—and, if re-elected, I pledge to do all in my power to help replace human inefficiency with Cyber justice in the courts of this county!
"We've seen what other counties have done with Cyber judges. We've witnessed the effectiveness of cybernetic units in our own Appellate Division.... And I can promise you twice as many prosecutions at half the cost to the taxpayers ... with modern, streamlined Cyber justice!""We've seen what other counties have done with Cyber judges. We've witnessed the effectiveness of cybernetic units in our own Appellate Division.... And I can promise you twice as many prosecutions at half the cost to the taxpayers ... with modern, streamlined Cyber justice!"


Walhfred Anderson accepted the file from his aging, nearsighted clerk. He saw that the case had been assigned originally to Department 42. It was the case he had been warned about by the Presiding Judge.
Walhfred Anderson struggled to focus all his attention on the complaint before him. His craggy features, once described as resembling a benign bulldog, grew rigid with concentration. The Judge had a strong sense of honor about dividing his attention in Court. A case was not just a case; it was a human being whose past, present and future were wrapped up in the charge against him.
"Your Honor," the District Attorney broke in, impatiently, "if the Court will permit, I can summarize this case very quickly...."
The tone of his voice implied:
A Cyber judge would speed things up around here. Feed the facts into the proprioceptor, and they'd be stored and correlated instantly.
Perhaps so, Walhfred Anderson thought, suddenly tired, though the morning was still young. At eighty-six you couldn't go on fighting and resisting much longer. Maybe he should resign, and listen to the speeches at a farewell luncheon, and let a Cyber take over. The Cybers were fast. They ruled swiftly and surely on points of law. They separated fact from fallacy. They were not led down side avenues of justice by human frailty. Their vision was not blurred by emotion. And yet ... Judge Anderson looked to Justice Holmes for a clarifying thought, but the Justice's eyes were opaque, inscrutable.
Judge Anderson wearily settled back in his tall chair, bracing the ache in his back against the leather padding.
"You may proceed," he told the District Attorney.


Thank for the suggestion! I also found it in my search and while interesting, it’s not the one I’m looking for

Unlikely to be the correct answer but if you're looking for robot judge stories:
"The Looking Glass of the Law" (1978) short story by Kevin O'Donnell, Jr. My notes say "A computerized judge plants hallucinations of agonizing pain as punishment, appropriate to crime".
Also "I See You" (1959) • novelette by Harry Harrison (variant of Robot Justice). A convict tries to hide inside a robot judge but someone is there already.
